# Three Google Sheets' data graphs (pie charts) in one graph

Tags: google-sheets, filter, charts, google-sheets-formula, pie-chart

I have three google sheets of data in one spreadsheet. these sheets containing the data of ABC Town students. ABC Town has 3 Streets called Street 1, Street 2 and Street 3.

- **Street 1** has **10** Students in different grades.
- **Street 2** has **6** Students in different grades.
- **Street 3** has **2** Students in different grades.

Every sheet has Students Grade summary Pie Graph. Now What I need is,
I have to combine these three pie charts into one chart to get a final summary of three sheets. how can I do this? Please.

This is my spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NmCSRPaoGCpuyfxv24z2-M8TNktBjHNt7BoaMF6LCJY/edit?usp=sharing

explained in image:

[image]

Comment: @player0 thanks mate.. i'll try... btw, my one is separate three sheets of data nah... above link answer is for one sheet data nah? will it help me? please.

Comment: ohh @player0.. you deleted your commnt ??

Comment: I had a look... you can join your data under one sheet and then construct your graph there. but no, it doesn't matter you have it on 3 separate sheets.

Comment: In your combined chart, do you just want to repeat the same data except on an aggregate basis?

Comment: yeah @a-burge... you got it. please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

or maybe you just want to combine all 3 charts (?) like:

[image: 0]

### **[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qbCgheemDQ8G7chb8FbezoCJxsJJVcv__RA5sGY44lo/edit?usp=sharing)**

Comment: awesome mate.. finallly got solution.. :) Thanks much

Comment: Hi @player0 I have a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72170745/multi-level-nested-pie-chart-in-google-sheets
I will donate to you for a solution

Comment: @CoolkcaH just to be clear... you are looking for this solution - https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6EIO.png - but with sum instead of count, and not this answer you commented to, right?

Comment: @player0 yes sorry I commented in the wrong answer, I meant that one or this one https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDHzI.png  the one you show looks easier to understand, but would need the sum numbers inside the outer part that is the category, and the inner part is the sub-category with name+sum too

Answer (score 2):

if you map out your data the right way you can create pie chart with sub-slices for each of your three pie charts and then you will just layer them. here is an example:

---

[image]

- your dataset of **`A1:C`** is not in "good" shape for creating a chart, so first, you will need to re-shape it by adding few formulas in auxiliary columns which you can hide when done
- in cell **E1** paste this formula and create a base pie chart. this will create even ratio between **`Libaries`**. select primary color for each libary and maximze chart style


  ```
  ={"Libaries"\""; {TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(1&" "; 
    COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B; B2:B<>""))));" "))\ 
    UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B; B2:B<>""))}}
  ```
- if you got **`#ERROR!`** paste this into **E1** cell:


  ```
  ={"Libaries",""; {TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(1&" ", 
    COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>""))))," ")), 
    UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>""))}}
  ```
- paste this formula in **G1** cell to create labels:


  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(JOIN("×"; 
   TRANSPOSE(REPT(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B&"×"; B2:B<>"")); 2))); "×"))
  ```
- then paste this formula in **G2** to create dataset for 2nd chart:


  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT($A$2:$C); 
   "select count(Col3), Col3 
    where Col1 is not null and Col2='"&G1&"'
    group by Col3 
    label count(Col3)''"; 0))
  ```
- after this you will need correction formula which can correct position of the first set of pie slices. paste this in **G6** cell and create 2nd pie chart from range **G2:H**. then play with colors and set color of the correction pie on **`None`**


  ```
  =IF(SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT($A$2:$C); 
   "select count(Col3) 
    where Col1 is not null and Col2='"&G1&"'
    group by Col3 
    label count(Col3)''"; 0)))>3;
   SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT($A$2:$C); 
   "select Col3, count(Col3) 
    where Col1 is not null and Col2='"&G1&"'
    group by Col3 
    label count(Col3)''"; 0)))*2; 6)
  ```
- when done, overlay 1st chart with 2nd chart
- then paste this formula in **i4** cell (this will be dataset for 3rd chart)


  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT($A$2:$C); 
   "select count(Col3), Col3 
    where Col1 is not null and Col2='"&I1&"'
    group by Col3 
    label count(Col3)''"; 0))
  ```
- next you need correction again. this time twice. paste this formula in **i2** and **i7**


  ```
  =SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT($A$2:$C), 
   "select Col3, count(Col3) 
    where Col1 is not null and Col2='"&I1&"'
    group by Col3 
    label count(Col3)''", 0)))
  ```
- now you can construct 3rd pie chart from range **i2:J**. again play with colors and hide correction slices. when done overlay it on top of 1st and 2nd chart
- when done paste this formula in **K4** cell (this will be dataset for the 4th pie chart)


  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT($A$2:$C); 
   "select count(Col3), Col3 
    where Col1 is not null and Col2='"&K1&"'
    group by Col3 
    label count(Col3)''"; 0))
  ```
- and again you need to correct the position with this formula pasted in **K2** cell


  ```
  =IF(SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT($A$2:$C); 
   "select count(Col3) 
    where Col1 is not null and Col2='"&K1&"'
    group by Col3 
    label count(Col3)''"; 0)))>3;
   SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT($A$2:$C); 
   "select Col3, count(Col3) 
    where Col1 is not null and Col2='"&K1&"'
    group by Col3 
    label count(Col3)''"; 0)))*2; 6)
  ```
- create 4th pie chart from range **K2:L**, play with colors, hide correction slice, possition it on all previous charts
- if you want to put up some labels then you can **insert drawings** and overlay it once again

[image]

---

## [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GUN49WLPdmGQHt7EtoqQ183KQ--7NcKaQS4DUAycC14/edit#gid=1100830887)

Comment: I'll try dear.... seems bit complicated. but I'm giving try... thnks much dear...

Comment: @gsdgs create a copy of the demo spreadsheet and dissect it. once you check all setting of the chart and play a bit with it, you will totally get it