# Multi-level nested pie chart in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, charts, google-visualization

I need a multi-level nested pie chart in google sheets.
To show number sums in categories and sub-categories. Can use code or just formulas.

Or if a system similar to google sheets already has a easy configurable nested pie-chart I can consider using it.

Here is a sample sheet with 2 charts I want to combine:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TvOf_tRNFS4zqbYR8EMGfTH1krI_iX9resrQ_AwmGZ8/edit?usp=sharing

[image: data]
[image: chart1]
[image: chart2]

It can be similar to the one here, but with sums instead of counts:

[Three Google Sheets' data graphs (pie charts) in one graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54864419/three-google-sheets-data-graphs-pie-charts-in-one-graph)

Or a D3 Sunburst Partition.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see why this is different to the question you linked? Seems the exact same problem to me.

Comment: Its similar but was looking for a specific solution and perhaps alternatives that are easier to implement

Answer (score 4):

dynamic fx:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({TRANSPOSE(QUERY({A1:C}, "select sum(Col3),Col1 where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col3)'Base Pie'"));
 {"♀", IFERROR(1/(1/TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(IF(SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A))<SEQUENCE(1, COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A)), 
 QUERY({A2:C}, "select sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col3)''"), )*1), SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A), 1, 1, )))));
 QUERY(QUERY({A2:C, ROW(A2:A)}, "select Col2,max(Col3) where Col3 is not null group by Col4,Col2 pivot Col1"), "offset 1", )};
 {"♂", IFERROR(1/(1/TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(IF(SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A))>SEQUENCE(1, COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A)), 
 QUERY({A2:C}, "select sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col3)''"), )*1), SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A), 1, 1, )))))}})
```

- the formula takes data in A:C range and creates all necessary steps, columns and rows that will feed pie charts.
- rows labeled `♀♂` serve as pie chart ratio correctors
- column E can be used as a subcategory labeling system if needed
- in the same manner row 3 can be used as labels for base pie
- first, we create a base pie chart (from the black row) which will serve as background:

[image]

- next, for each colored column we create a separate pie chart that we overlay on top of the base pie chart. note that colors and sub-colors needs to be selected **manually** for each slice by double-clicking a given slice and selecting either color or **none** in the case of `♀♂` slices

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

and repeat for the next column...

[image]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E7pd4IB6eTYzXFtvBaH7IA68k7UJxdCpzM7xyRER-nw/edit#gid=1896434818)

Answer (score 2):

E2:

```
=QUERY({A2:C}, "select Col1,sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col3)''")
```

G2:

```
={FILTER(B2:C, A2:A=E2); "", SUM(FILTER(B2:C, A2:A<>E2))}
```

I2:

```
={"", SUM(FILTER(C2:C, A2:A=E2)); FILTER(B2:C, A2:A=E3); "", SUM(FILTER(B2:C, A2:A=E4))}
```

K2:

```
={"", SUM(FILTER(B2:C, A2:A<>E4)); FILTER(B2:C, A2:A=E4)}
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E7pd4IB6eTYzXFtvBaH7IA68k7UJxdCpzM7xyRER-nw/copy)

Comment: This is great, but really hard to replicate, did you use code to generate it or you did everything manually? The real world data I have has many more categories, and I cant even find a way to select all the graphs being used, and the colors look also manually picked because copying the sheet to another causes the colors to change randomly. Can you explain the process you use to get this result so I can replicate it? Please contact me if possible I sent a message on gogetfunding. Thanks

Comment: @CoolkcaH all done manually. I added an alternative solution with more details. apart from this solution where formulae were derived to fit targetted example, the alternative solution takes the dataset and automatically creates all necessities.